# Chef repository: should I commit .chef/ and .berkshelf/ folders?

Tags: chef-infra

I'm doing the chef tutorial and I've downloaded the chef repository zip from https://learnchef.opscode.com.

In the tutorial it says to add everything to git (`git add .`) but I'm wary: should I really commit in the repo those hidden folders:

- .chef/
- .berkshelf/

I'm wondering because `.chef/` contains private key files.

Comment: I commit everything except private keys. You can add your private keys into .gitignore file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would add the following to .gitignore:

```
.chef/*.pem
.chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret
```

For berkshelf, I believe the default .gitignore is generated as:

```
.vagrant
Berksfile.lock
*~
*#
.#*
\#*#
.*.sw[a-z]
*.un~
/cookbooks

# Bundler
Gemfile.lock
bin/*
.bundle/*

.kitchen/
.kitchen.local.yml
```

Comment: You mean to **not** add the `*.pem` files? Those are private keys

Comment: Yeah I think he meant add them to the .gitignore file for .chef